# 'bundle install' for a local gem is not resolving dependencies, while 'gem install' does

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I have a local gem (enterprise-0.0.1.gem) in a directory '/home/enterprise/pkg'.
It has dependency on active_directory gem (v 1.5.5), which was specified in it's enterprise.gemspec file like this :-

```
gem.add_dependency("active_directory")
```

In my Application's Gemfile, I add the following line:-

```
gem 'enterprise', '0.0.1', path => '/home/enterprise/pkg'
```

When I do

> bundle install

from my application's source directory, only the enterprise gem is installed. Hence, I hit runtime errors for the reference to active_directory gem.

But when I do

> gem install /home/enterprise/pkg/enterprise-0.0.1.gem

the dependencies are resolved and I can see the active_directory gem in the gem list.

Why is there a discrepancy in the dependency resolution with bundler, and not with rubygems.

Kindly let me know if I need to provide more information about the environment.
Ruby: 1.9.2,
RubyGems: 1.8.24,
Bundler: 1.1.5,
rvm: 1.9.2.

My enterprise.gemspec file for reference :-

```
 # -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
   require File.expand_path('../lib/enterprise/version', __FILE__)

   Gem::Specification.new do |gem|
      gem.authors       = ["example"]
      gem.email         = ["example@example.com"]
      gem.description   = %q{Enterprise Gem: example}
      gem.summary       = %q{Services: Authentication, Access Control}
      gem.homepage      = "http://example.com"  
      gem.files         = %w[
                       README.md
                       Rakefile
                       Gemfile
                       Gemfile.lock
                       enterprise.gemspec
                       lib/enterprise.rb
                       lib/enterprise/auth_service.rb
                       lib/enterprise/version.rb
                       ]
     gem.executables   = gem.files.grep(%r{^bin/}).map{ |f| File.basename(f) }
     gem.test_files    = gem.files.grep(%r{^(test|spec|features)/})
     gem.name          = "enterprise"
     gem.require_paths = ["lib"]
     gem.version       = Enterprise::VERSION
     gem.add_dependency("active_directory")
   end
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and ended up deleting the Gemfile.lock to resolve the issue.

Comment: Removing the Gemfile.lock entry for my local gem did solve the dependency problem for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Does your gem, have a Gemfile with the following contents?

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Specify your gem's dependencies in enterprise.gemspec
gemspec
```

Try adding a require in your application gemspec

```
gem 'enterprise', '0.0.1', path => '/home/enterprise/pkg', :require => "active_directory"
```

Comment: Yes, I do have these in my enterprise gem's Gemfile.
Do you require my gemspec file ?

Comment: No, it does not seem to install the active_directory gem with the :require option. It behaves the same way as before. Only the enterprise gem is installed.

Comment: I am just curious what is the standard practice for using a custom local gem. Doing a [gem install 'enterprise' & bundle install] everytime I move my application to a production server does not make sense.

Comment: well I guess I would just add 'active_directory' to the application Gemfile?

Comment: and you will want to do a `bundle install` every time you deploy to production, it won't pull in any that have not changed - `bundle install --deployment` - guessing you have already been through this documentation: http://gembundler.com/rationale.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `gem.add_runtime_dependency` in your `gemspec` -- not `add_dependency` and that ought to require the gem whether you add it to your `Gemfile` or not.

Comment: Apparently, they are aliases for each other (SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24334371/1042144, Ruby docs: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Gem/Specification.html#method-i-add_runtime_dependency)