# Difference between add_dependency and add_runtime_dependency?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

What is the difference between using `add_dependency` and `add_runtime_dependency` in a Rails engine's gemspec?

For example:

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.add_dependency 'jquery-rails'
  s.add_runtime_dependency 'jquery-rails'
end
```

**What's the difference between them?**

Answer (score 44, accepted):

They are the same. `add_dependency` is just an [alias](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1//libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Gem/Specification.html#method-i-add_runtime_dependency) for `add_runtime_dependency`.

Comment: Are there any plans to deprecate `add_dependency`?

Comment: For anyone else wondering, [there are no plans to deprecate add_dependency](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/1349)